# Minimum separation between two bodies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

> Let Bodies A and B be kept at two points in the x-y plane. They are allowed to move in the x-y plane.
>   Suppose the velocity of B is constant, and the speed of body A is fixed, how must the body A move so that the bodies A and B get as close as possible at any point of time. The two bodies start from rest at the same time.

My approach:

I assumed some general intitial coordinates of bodies A and B and velocity of body B to be $a \wedge{i}+ b \wedge{j}$ and of A to be $v_x \wedge{i} + v_y \wedge{j}$.

The situation seemed a bit complicated in ground frame, I assumed a general time t, calculated the position of bodies A and B, and tried to find the minimum distance between bodies A and B(by differentiation), but it got too messy.

I also tried in frame of reference of B but couldn't make much progress.

Intuitively, I feel that the direction of velocity of A must be given is independent of the initial coordinates of A and B and it much be such that velocity of A is perpendicular to the relative velocity of B wrt A.

Is this true? How to prove this?

(Sorry for the terrible latex. I am not getting how to write I cap, j cap)

Comment: I think I understand your problem statement after rereading it all a couple times.  Your first paragraph is very vague and misleading if I understand the problem correctly.  Both A and B are moving with constant velocity, but the direction of A’s velocity is not given and we are asked to choose that direction so as to minimize the distance at closest approach between A and B.  Is that what you intend to ask?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the bad wording

Comment: “I am not getting how to write i cap, j cap” Write \hat{i} for $\hat{i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
I suggest a different approach.
First, choose the coordinates such that body $B$ is at the origin for $t=0$ and let its velocity be along the $x$ axis, so $\vec{v_B} = v_B \vec{i}$.

Body $A$ would start somewhere in the plane $\vec{r_A}(t=0) = x_0 \vec{i} + y_0 \vec{j}$, with velocity $\vec{v_A} = v_A^x \vec{i} + v_A^y \vec{j}$.

Then we could change the referential to body $B$. In this referential, at time $t=0$, $A$ would be at $\vec{r_A'}(t=0) = x_0 \vec{i} + y_0 \vec{j}$ but it's moving with velocity $\vec{v_A'} = (v_A^x - v_b) \vec{i} + v_A^y \vec{j}$.

Can you solve it from this point onward?